# Handle missing values in np.select

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, na

I am trying to settle a new column 'Score' to my panda `DataFrame`
I found that the best way could be to use the `np.select()` function.

Yet, I have some missing values in my dataframe, for which i would like to return **False**, but don't find a way of doing so.

My last attempt look like the following:

```
score_conditions = [
    ((df['column1']).replace({'<NA>': np.nan}).fillna(False) > 15),
    (df['column2'] > 5),
    (df['column3'] < 1)
]   
score_choices = [3, 2, 1]

df['Score'] = np.select(score_conditions, score_choices, default=0)
```

I am a bit lost at the differences between panda's NA and numpy NaN which may be different?
The current `<NA>` are usually part of Int64 columns.

I have missing values in most columns (maybe 5 over 10 condition columns), but would still like to have the score computed when 1 or more values are available.

Here is an example dataframe:

```
df = DataFrame({'column1' : [5,16,<NA>,24], 'column2' : [5,6,3,1], 'column3' : [<NA>,0,0,<NA>]})
```

The expected outcome would be:

```
For index 0: 0 #zero condition are met, when values are available
For index 1: 3 #all conditions are met
For index 2: 1 #only condition in 3rd columns is met, when values are available
For index 3: 1 #only condition in 1st columns is met, when values are available
```

Thank you,

Comment: Can you provide a sample input dataframe and the expected output?

Comment: For me working perfectly, if use `df['column1'] > 15` it return `True` for greater values like `15` and `False` for `NA` and less/equal 15.

Comment: thank you for your comments! if I try to print: `df['column1'] > 15` ; I get the following return: `0    <NA>
Name: column1, dtype: boolean`

With `df['column1'].dtype`
output is: `Int64Dtype()`

Comment: @ArthurL - Can you upgrade pandas?

Comment: First of all, `Int64` is a special pandas datatype which can hold `int64` normal values and a special `<NA>` value to denote a missing value. `np.nan` can only exist in floating point columns, and the string `'<NA>'` on object columns. And `False` cannot exist in `intxx`, `Intxx` nor floating point columns. Pandas offer *natural* conversions between any *not available* value whatever the type (except the **string** `'<NA'>`), but if you write a `False` into a column, it will be converter to `object`. Until you understand that, you will never be able to correctly handle your missing values...

Comment: Merci @SergeBallesta! I understand now a bit more the difference, and will definitely need to review the basics again in order to keep learning.

Comment: @ArthurL: I have posted a more detailed answer below. Bonne chance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First idea is upgrade pandas to last version.

---

Another idea is convert `NA` to `np.nan` by convert values to floats:

```
df['column1'] > 15
```

to:

```
df['column1'].astype(float) > 15
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be a minor syntax thing. Basically,  should be in double quotes, as it's a not a native python or pandas or numpy datatype. At which point, the columns become type('O') signifying that they are objects. I slightly modified your code and got an answer, although it's not quite the desired score values, it works exactly as designed:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'column1' : [5,16,"<NA>",24], 'column2' : [5,6,3,1], 'column3' : ["<NA>",0,0,"<NA>"]})


score_conditions = [
    ((df['column1']).replace({'<NA>': np.nan}).fillna(False) > 15),
    (df['column2'] > 5),
    (df['column3'].replace({'<NA>': np.nan}).fillna(False) < 1)
]   
score_choices = [3, 2, 1]

df['Score'] = np.select(score_conditions, score_choices, default=0)
```

Comment: thank you for taking the time to answer ! I will go with the solution from jezrael which seems cleaner, but indeed it may only have been some syntax issues as well.

Answer (score 0):

Datatypes do matter, and anyway `fillna` is all you need.

Let's use your example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'column1' : [5,16,pd.NA,24], 'column2' : [5,6,3,1], 'column3' : [pd.NA,0,0,pd.NA]})
>>> score_conditions = [
    (df['column1'] > 15),
    (df['column2'] > 5),
    (df['column3'] < 1)
]
>>> for i in score_conditions: print(i)

0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
Name: column1, dtype: bool
0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
Name: column2, dtype: bool
0    False
1     True
2     True
3    False
Name: column3, dtype: bool
```

you directly get the expected values because the columns have `object` datatypes:

```
>>> print(df.dtypes)
column1    object
column2     int64
column3    object
dtype: object
```

But in a comment you explained that your columns had `Int64` datatypes (note the capital I). So let us force that datatype:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'column1' : [5,16,pd.NA,24], 'column2' : [5,6,3,1], 'column3' : [pd.NA,0,0,pd.NA]}, dtype=pd.Int64Dtype())
>>> score_conditions = [
    (df['column1'] > 15),
    (df['column2'] > 5),
    (df['column3'] < 1)
]
>>> for i in score_conditions: print(i)

0    False
1     True
2     <NA>
3     True
Name: column1, dtype: boolean
0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
Name: column2, dtype: boolean
0    <NA>
1    True
2    True
3    <NA>
Name: column3, dtype: boolean
```

Patatras, we find the `<NA>` values you wanted to avoid! At least it reproduces your problem...

The solution is `fillna`:

```
>>> score_conditions = [
    (df['column1'] > 15).fillna(False),
    (df['column2'] > 5).fillna(False),
    (df['column3'] < 1).fillna(False)
]
>>> for i in score_conditions: print(i)

0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
Name: column1, dtype: boolean
0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
Name: column2, dtype: boolean
0    False
1     True
2     True
3    False
Name: column3, dtype: boolean
```

And no floating point conversion is required...